# How can I fix the issue with many-to-many relationship definition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem like this I ask another question related to this code today.I got solved that problem, but now it giving and another error.

```
public function addSubject(Request $request){
        $student=User::find($request->invisible);
        $classsubjects = $request['classsubjects'];
        $student->classSubjects()->attach($classsubjects);
        return redirect()->route('users.index')
            ->with('flash_message',
             'User successfully added.');
}
```

Here i am giving the definition of ClassSubject Model and User model definition.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','language'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {   
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    public function classSubject()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClassSubject');
    }

    public function classSubjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ClassSubject');

    }


}
```

This is my classSubject model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ClassSubject extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
         'class_room_id','subject_id','teacher_id'
    ];

     public function classRoom()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ClassRoom','class_room_id','id');
    }

     public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id');
    }

     public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','teacher_id','id');
    }


    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');

    }






}
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lcurve.class_subject_user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `class_subject_user` (`class_subject_id`, `user_id`) values (3, 4), (1, 4))
```

Should i need to create a table like the error message saying.

Comment: What is the name of the pivot table between `ClassSubject` and `User`? Can you post its model?

Comment: should i need to ceate a intermediate pivote table?

Comment: Yes. To have belongsToMany relationshinp you need a pivot table. I'll post an example as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a pivot table to handle this. Ex:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ClassSubjectUser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
         'class_subject_id','user_id'
    ];

    protected $table = 'class_subject_user';
}
```

And then, when defining the relationships, you should set the name of the table and the keys.

In User model:

```
public function classSubjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ClassSubject', 'class_subject_user', 'class_subject_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In ClassSubject model:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'class_subject_user', 'user_id', 'class_subject_id');
}
```

This will set the belongsToMany relationship correctly.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships